# Rails 5 - Connectivity issue with MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, tiny-tds, ruby-2.3

I am trying to build a `ROR` app with `Ruby 2.3.3` and `Rails 5.0.1` but when connecting to SQl server 2008 I am getting an error which says

> TinyTDS::Error (Adaptive server connection failed)

I am using the latest version of `tiny_tds gem (1.3.0)` and latest version of `activerecord_sqlserver_adapter (5.0)`. Due to this I am unable to start my app and hence not able to proceed.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Spoorthi NG

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Rails 5 unfortunately. Your only option is to downgrade to an older version of `activerecord_sqlserver_adapter` AND and older version of Rails. You can read more about the specifics in here: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/